# Blazor Server authentication problem : NotAuthorized not working

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor server app, I've created a custom `authenticationStateProvider` to validate user from my own database. It works correctly, but in my `app.razor` page, I've set `NotAuthorized` tag to redirect anonymous user to login page, but that doesn't work.

Here is my `app.razor` page markup:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="@_loadedAssemblies">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLoginPage />
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <span class="persianFontSans">Authorizing ...</span>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>            
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>    
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>The page not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotFound />
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

And here is my `customAuthenticationProvider` class:

```
public class SmartMISAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage _sessionStorage;
    private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    public SmartMISAuthenticationStateProvider(ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage)
    {
        _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
         try
         {
             var accountInfoStorageResult = await _sessionStorage.GetAsync<AccountInfo>("_accountSession");
             var accountInfoSession = accountInfoStorageResult.Success ? accountInfoStorageResult.Value : null;

             if (accountInfoSession == null)
                 return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));

             var claims = new List<Claim>();
             claims.Add(new Claim("AccountID", accountInfoSession.AccountID));
             claims.Add(new Claim("AccountType", accountInfoSession.AccountType));
             claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, accountInfoSession.FullName));
             claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, accountInfoSession.PhoneNumber));

             var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "SmartMISAuth"));

             return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
         }
     }

     public async Task UpdateAuthenticationStateAsync(AccountInfo accountInfo)
     {
         ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

         if (accountInfo != null)
         {
             await _sessionStorage.SetAsync("_accountSession", accountInfo);

             var claims = new List<Claim>();
             claims.Add(new Claim("AccountID", accountInfo.AccountID));
             claims.Add(new Claim("AccountType", accountInfo.AccountType));
             claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, accountInfo.FullName));
             claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, accountInfo.PhoneNumber));

             claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
         }
         else
         {
             await _sessionStorage.DeleteAsync("_accountSession");
             claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
         }

         NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
     }
 }
```

Where is the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

**----- Updated ---**

When i insert [Authorize] attribute for Index razor page, it works, but when insert it in MainLayout layout page, not working!

Can anybody help me how to implement a mechanism when user is not authenticated, redirect to login page for all pages (instead of set attribute for each razor page)?

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i found my answer!
Simple transfer my authentication code from app.razor to mainLayout component and manage user authentication as follow :

```
<AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            @* Your content here *@
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <RedirectToLoginPage />
        </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

This code works for all your pages which inherits from mainLayout!
That's it.